# tailwind css margin class not applying margin to component, react

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

Why I am not getting a margin if I add a class  of `my-30 mr-auto ml-auto` to component:

```js
import React from "react";

import SignIn from "../../components/sign-in/sign-in.component";
import SignUp from "../../components/sign-up/sign-up.component";

const SignInAndSignUpPage = () => (
    <div className="flex justify-center my-30 mr-auto ml-auto">
        <SignIn />
        <SignUp />
    </div>
);

export default SignInAndSignUpPage;
```

The result is :

[image]

but the expected result is:
[image]

How can I achieve the expected result using tailwind classes

**note: I have installed the tailwind css library using npm and other classes work fine but this class is not working**

Comment: Because you are not using `grid`, you need to add margin inside the `<SignIn />` or `<SignUp />` component directly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are various way to get the result:

1. Add container for each component and give margin to it:

```
const SignInAndSignUpPage = () => (
    <div className="flex justify-center my-30">
        <div className="mr-4">
            <SignIn />
        </div>        
        <div className="ml-4">
            <SignUp />
        </div>
    </div>
);
```

2. Use grid

```
const SignInAndSignUpPage = () => (
    <div className="grid grid-cols-2 space-x-2">
        <SignIn />
        <SignUp />
    </div>
);
```

3. Add margin inside the component `<SignIn />` or `<SignUp />` or both

Answer (score 0):

If the class is not applied in your HTML element at all.

It could be an issue with your `tailwind.config.js`.

Make sure the file you are working on is referenced in the `content` array.

```
module.exports = {
  content: [
    './directory/of_the_files/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}'
  ]
}
```

It was applying some tailwind classes but not the margin for me.

PS: I suggest using `mx-auto` class, instead of `ml-auto mr-auto` for readability  purpose.